# Understanding the 20-Bit Addressing in 8086 Memory Architecture: Why Not 18 Bits for Base and 16 Bits for Offset?

Tags: microprocessor, assembly, addressing, x86

I'm curious about the memory addressing in the 8086 microprocessor. Given that there are four segments and 16 bits for the offset address, the total address space is 20 bits. I'm wondering why there's a need for 20 bits in the address; wouldn't using 18 bits for the base address and 16 bits for the offset address be sufficient? Can someone explain the rationale behind the 20-bit address in the context of 8086 memory architecture?

Comment: Given the age of the 8086, you might get a better answer on [Retro Computing.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).  I've seen many answers where the information's provided with a historical context.

Comment: Emad, The 8088/8086 used four segment registers -- 16 bits in width and representing the upper 16 bits of one **A** input to a 20-bit adder with the lower 4 bits as '0' -- with offset addresses, also called a logical address -- that was also 16 bits in width and representing the other **B** input to the same 20-bit adder with the upper 4 bits as '0'. The output of the 20-bit adder was called the physical address. Before I attempt any answer here, I'd like to know if you already understand this. And note that an 18-bit register would have been a huge complication. Do you not see why???

Comment: I can't really see how to help answer your question until I am able to understand how it is that you think an 18-bit register would even work, at all, let alone that it would be in any way better. 16-bit segment registers can be loaded with 16-bit constants, which the instruction set can handle. But loading an 18-bit register? How would you propose to do that, exactly?

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks for your answer. i was able to understand why they did that after reading a great comprehensible answer from quera. If im understanding correctly, the memory is actually divided into 16 segments but we interpret it as 4 segments; meaning that the base addresses must be updated after each segment.

Comment: @EmadK You may or may not understand yet. The memory was broken up into 16-byte granules. The address 0001:0000 produced the exact same physical address as did 0000:0010. (I'm putting the segment address first, the offset address second.) Is that how you see it? Or not? So the physical address of 001000 could be accessed using 0000:1000 or 0001:0FF0 or 0002:0FE0 or 0003:0FD0, etc. Lots of ways to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i think my main problem was i misunderstood the concept and thought the memory is actually divided into 4 segments. I think i understand it now.

Comment: @EmadK There's ways to see how to use this. But there's a process needed to get used to some of the ideas. I spent many years of my life programming commercial products in assembly on 8088 machines (only once on an 8086.) I also worked at Intel on the BX chipset. So I know a few things and I'm quite comfortable with the system and have a library of textbooks I might recommend if you are planning to use the device. But I rather expect not. You write as though you are more curious than someone contemplating their use.

Comment: @EmadK The even older 8080 systems (Altair 8800 and IMSAI 8080A -- which I have sitting here, by the way) were limited to 64k. By modifying the bus to extend its address width and by including a short 4-bit (thereabouts) latch, it was possible for software to access more than 64k. But only in banks of 64k. The first systems were a nightmare. You'd load the latch and instantly be in a new bank. Later, wiser people mangled the addressing so that a small upper region was protected against banking, allowing bits of code to always be present. But it was a mess.

Comment: @periblepsis Im taking a course at my university, and my professor will be covering the 8086 architecture. Ive already watched an introduction video, but i got a bit confused when it came to memory segmentation. if you have any book recommendations that could help me better understand the 8086? Id really appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: @EmadK The 80386 was already a "from the '60's multix-based" concept in designer's minds. But marketing needed something before the 80386 was ready. So they hacked the thing and dumped out the 80286. It had a protected mode. But it could not get out of it and back to "real mode" which emulated the older 8088, without a full hardware reset. So to make that work, they added code to the keyboard -- yes, the keyboard. They would tell the keyboard to reset the motherboard. Seriously! And they used clock chip memory to figure out whether this was a cold or hot boot. Those were the days.

Comment: @periblepsis Interestingly, that banking system is how several video game systems worked, well after the 8080. I know the super nintendo used banks, and the original nintendo didn't support it on its own but most game cartridges had bank-switching hardware on them in addition to the ROM chips.

Comment: Is "18 bits" a typo? Surely you would go downward, say 8 bits, rather than making a register larger than the data bus width?  Only 4 additional bits were needed (for the desired addressing extension); would the better question be: why use additional bits beyond this, and how many?

Comment: @Hearth When I built my first Altair 8800 in early 1975, memory was very expensive. So banking was not, at the time, a pressing need. What really drove the need (there was need, but not like this) was when visicalc came out on the Apple II. I remember walking into an Apple store where it was "only geeks, playing games" in the store when, the very next week, it was "suits" walking in and buying 2, 3, or even 10 machines at once! Visicalc created Apple's success. By the way I still do some assembly coding on the NES and SNES machines here. I re-wrote a commercial assembler for that purpose, too.

Comment: @Hearth I do miss the old high speed paper tape punch/readers. (Okay, I also miss the ASR-33 and the KSR-35, too.) I also miss having a full front panel with lights and switches (basically, exposing the complete JTAG chain to a front panel!) I have a contact in EU who has working ASR-33 and KSR-35, who doesn't want them. But is busy with family. I may yet convince him to send them half way cross the world. I can hope. ;)

Comment: @periblepsis In my experience, offering to help take care of shipping paperwork, as well as costs, makes people a lot more likely to want to send something internationally.

Comment: @Hearth First thing I did, of course. He's teetering. But there's no avoiding him playing some role where he has it stored, no matter how much I try to help from my end. I just have to wait. What shocked me most was to hear of a fully functional KSR-35. I spent a year working on one. Those things are beasts!